# How to explicitly define a variable as static in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to explicitly define any variable as static in Python so that only one copy of it is created in memory and whenever the program is executed only that copy is modified and not every time a new copy is generated.

Comment: Python doesn't have static variables

Comment: You could use some sort of shared memory (`shmat` or memory mapping) but that has to be maintained by some sort of daemon process.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Even in programming languages where "static" is meaningful, static variables don't work the way you describe - at least, according to how you've been understood here.

Comment: Like in Java when we define a class variable/type as static then if we create multiple objects of that class all the objects would share only that one copy of a static variable. This is unlike to any other normal variable because for a normal class variable each and every object of that class would have a copy of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

> "whenever the program is executed"

**You can't keep a variable's value between multiple executions of a program.**

You could do this instead:

1. Write the content of your variable into a file before exiting
2. Open the file and read its content at the beginning of your program
3. Use the value you read to initialize your variable

Comment: Thanks...for this solution...tried it and actually works.

Comment: But when we think this in terms of a large scale reading and writing to a file every time sometimes becomes quite expensive.But this works nonetheless. Thoughts please.